# Need to fetch the row with maximum zeroes

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is to  fetch the row with maximum zeroes in a ROW for a sample structure like:

```
0   0   0   1
0   1   0   1
1   0   0   1
```

Can someone help me with this on mysql?

Comment: Your  structure is for one string column or on for 4 number column?

Comment: What's the expected result if two different rows have the same minimum? And if two equal rows have it?

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: is it 4 int columns or one string column

Comment: They are integer columns and they are 4 numbered columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, 
       IF(Col1 = 0, 1, 0) + IF(Col2 = 0, 1, 0) + IF(Col3 = 0, 1, 0) + IF(Col4 = 0, 1, 0) AS s
FROM mytable
ORDER BY s DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Oh dear. I fear this maybe making a bad situation worse. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If table table only contains 0's and 1's, then simply return the row with the lowest column sum:

```
select *
from tablename
where c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 = (select min(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4) from tablename)
```

Will return both rows in case of a tie.